# Eclipse Step Over is not working as expected - Tomcat web app debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat, breakpoints

I am working on Eclipse tomcat web app debugging.

Eclipse IDE 2019-03 Step Over (F6) doesn't navigate into another method call implementation. 
It just simply returns value from the method call instead of getting actual flow of the method implementation.

I wanted to see full flow of the application using Step Over. Any help !!

Comment: Why would you expect Step **Over** to navigate **into** a method?

Comment: Basically to understand over all execution of the code.

Comment: Think about it like a hole in the ground. You step *over* the hole, to bypass it, or you step *into* the hole, to see it closer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Step Into (F5) if you want the debugger to enter the method bodies.

Comment: If I dont want to use F5. If i use f5 means then i need to put breakpoint every where on the code.

Comment: What are you talking about? F5  takes you one step forward, just like F6, the difference being that it enters the method bodies, when possible. You don't need any more breakpoints for that.